# RuntimeException after adding MongoDB policy provider extension

Tags: java, fiware, xacml, authzforce

I have made my own MongoDBPolicyProvider and I have integrated it into Authzforce server, but I'm unable to start the webapp (docker image fiware/authzforce-ce-server, release-8.1.0) because of this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid PDP configuration of domain 'YAT-5z9ZEemGyAJCrBEAAg' in file '/opt/authzforce-ce-server/data/domains/YAT-5z9ZEemGyAJCrBEAAg/pdp.xml': refPolicyProvider is not an instance of class org.ow2.authzforce.pap.dao.flatfile.xmlns.StaticFlatFileDAORefPolicyProvider as expected.
```

I think that somehow it is still trying to retrieve policies from a `StaticFlatFileDAORefPolicyProvider` policy provider.

- The extension's .jar is visible in server's classpath.
- Here is my pdp configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<pdp
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://authzforce.github.io/core/xmlns/pdp/6.0"
    xmlns:oa="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"
    version="6.0.0" enableXPath="false" strictAttributeIssuerMatch="false" maxVariableRefDepth="10" maxPolicyRefDepth="10">
    <refPolicyProvider
        id="refPolicyProvider"
        xmlns:ext="PRP/mongoDB"
        xsi:type="ext:MongoDBBasedPolicyProviderDescriptor"
        serverHost="localhost" serverPort="27017" dbName="PRP" collectionName="policies" />
    <rootPolicyProvider id="rootPolicyProvider" xsi:type="StaticRefBasedRootPolicyProvider">
       <policyRef>root-rbac-policyset</policyRef>
    </rootPolicyProvider>
</pdp>
```

- This is the MongoDBBasedPolicyProviderDescriptor:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MongoDBBasedPolicyProviderDescriptor")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MongoDBBasedPolicyProviderDescriptor extends AbstractPolicyProvider
{
    @XmlAttribute(name = "serverHost", required = true)
    protected String serverHost;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "serverPort", required = true)
    protected int serverPort;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "dbName", required = true)
    protected String dbName;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "collectionName", required = true)
    protected String collectionName;
}
```

I have done the process of integrating the PRP twice now, but I haven't been successful yet. I would appreciate any help in this direction.

Comment: Using a custom Policy Provider is not officially supported on FIWARE AuthzForce Server. You won't be able to manage it via the REST API. So you have to do things a bit manually.
Have you tried to follow AuthzForce Core documentation (link below)?
https://github.com/authzforce/core/wiki/Policy-Providers

Comment: @CyrilDangerville At the moment, I don't want to manage it via the API. Yes, that is precisely the link I followed.

Answer (score 0):

AuthzForce Server only works with `StaticFlatFileDAORefPolicyProvider` out-of-the-box. Still, I can suggest 2 alternative workarounds:

1) Implement your own [DomainsDao](https://static.javadoc.io/org.ow2.authzforce/authzforce-ce-core-pap-api/10.0.0/org/ow2/authzforce/core/pap/api/dao/DomainDao.html) supporting your `MongoDBBasedPolicyProviderDescriptor` instead of - or in addition to - `StaticFlatFileDAORefPolicyProvider`. You may use [FlatFileBasedDomainsDao](https://github.com/authzforce/pap-dao-flat-file/blob/master/src/main/java/org/ow2/authzforce/pap/dao/flatfile/FlatFileBasedDomainsDao.java) as basis, since this is the one used by AuthzForce Server natively. Then let's say we call this new implementation `MongoDBBasedDomainsDao`. So you need to change the [Spring configuration](https://github.com/authzforce/server/blob/develop/webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml) in `/opt/authzforce-ce-server/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml`: replace `org.ow2.authzforce.pap.dao.flatfile.FlatFileBasedDomainsDao` with MongoDBBasedDomainsDao's fully qualified class name. And add your implementation class/JAR and extra dependencies to the server classpath, usually in `/opt/authzforce-ce-server/webapp/WEB-INF/lib`.

2) Other option: use [AuthzForce Restful PDP](https://github.com/authzforce/restful-pdp) instead of AuthzForce Server. It works with any PolicyProvider. Check the [Extensions section for more info](https://github.com/authzforce/restful-pdp#extensions). Compared to the solution 1, the main advantage: no extra code required. But 2 downsides: a) No PAP API. Still the code is easily modifiable to add your own REST API for what you need.
   b) The PDP API is not multi-tenant. If you want multiple tenants/domains with separate PDP, you need multiple server instances (1 per domain).